# react-native-git-upgrade ERROR: fatal: No remote repository specified

Tags: javascript, git, react-native, npm, yarnpkg

I have problems when trying to upgrade using react-native-git-upgrade.
First issue was same with https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/11578.

Unfortunately, none of the solution on that thread helped me.

So, I trying to clear yarn cache.
I run `yarn cache clean`

And when I trying to run r`eact-native-git-upgrade` again,
This error appear:

E:\ReactProject\Aurai>react-native-git-upgrade

```
git-upgrade info Check for updates
git-upgrade info Using yarn 0.24.5
git-upgrade info Read package.json files
git-upgrade info Check declared version
git-upgrade info Check matching versions
git-upgrade info Check React peer dependency
git-upgrade info Check that Git is installed
git-upgrade info Get information from NPM registry
git-upgrade info Upgrading to React Native 0.48.4, React 16.0.0-alpha.12
git-upgrade info Setup temporary working directory
git-upgrade info Configure Git environment
git-upgrade info Init Git repository
git-upgrade info Add all files to commit
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in .babelrc.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in .buckconfig.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in .flowconfig.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in .gitattributes.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in .gitignore.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in __tests__/index.android.js.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in __tests__/index.ios.js.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in android/app/proguard-rules.pro.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in android/app/src/main/java/com/auraiid/id/MainActivity.java.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in android/app/src/main/java/com/auraiid/id/MainApplication.java.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in android/gradlew.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in android/keystores/BUCK.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in android/keystores/debug.keystore.properties.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in app.json.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in index.android.js.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in index.ios.js.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in ios/AuraiId-tvOS/Info.plist.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in ios/AuraiId-tvOSTests/Info.plist.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in ios/AuraiId.xcodeproj/xcshareddata/xcschemes/AuraiId-tvOS.xcscheme.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in ios/AuraiId.xcodeproj/xcshareddata/xcschemes/AuraiId.xcscheme.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in ios/AuraiId/AppDelegate.h.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in ios/AuraiId/Base.lproj/LaunchScreen.xib.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in ios/AuraiId/Images.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/Contents.json.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in ios/AuraiId/main.m.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in ios/AuraiIdTests/AuraiIdTests.m.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in ios/AuraiIdTests/Info.plist.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in native-base-theme/components/Badge.js.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in native-base-theme/components/Button.js.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in native-base-theme/components/Card.js.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in native-base-theme/components/CardItem.js.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in native-base-theme/components/CheckBox.js.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in native-base-theme/components/Container.js.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in native-base-theme/components/Content.js.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in native-base-theme/components/Fab.js.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in native-base-theme/components/Footer.js.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in native-base-theme/components/FooterTab.js.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in native-base-theme/components/Form.js.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in native-base-theme/components/H1.js.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in native-base-theme/components/H2.js.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in native-base-theme/components/H3.js.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in native-base-theme/components/Header.js.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in native-base-theme/components/Icon.js.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in native-base-theme/components/Input.js.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in native-base-theme/components/InputGroup.js.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in native-base-theme/components/Item.js.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in native-base-theme/components/Label.js.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in native-base-theme/components/ListItem.js.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in native-base-theme/components/Picker.android.js.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in native-base-theme/components/Picker.ios.js.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in native-base-theme/components/Radio.js.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in native-base-theme/components/Segment.js.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in native-base-theme/components/Separator.js.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in native-base-theme/components/Spinner.js.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in native-base-theme/components/Tab.js.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in native-base-theme/components/TabBar.js.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in native-base-theme/components/TabContainer.js.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in native-base-theme/components/TabHeading.js.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in native-base-theme/components/Text.js.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in native-base-theme/components/Textarea.js.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in native-base-theme/components/Title.js.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in native-base-theme/components/Toast.js.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in native-base-theme/components/View.js.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in native-base-theme/components/index.js.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in native-base-theme/variables/commonColor.js.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in native-base-theme/variables/material.js.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in native-base-theme/variables/platform.js.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in package.json.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
git-upgrade info Commit current project sources
git-upgrade info Create a tag before updating sources
git-upgrade info Generate old version template
git-upgrade info Add updated files to commit
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in .babelrc.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in .buckconfig.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in .flowconfig.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in .gitattributes.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in .gitignore.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in android/app/BUCK.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in android/app/build.gradle.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in android/app/proguard-rules.pro.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in android/app/src/main/res/values/strings.xml.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in android/app/src/main/res/values/styles.xml.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in android/build.gradle.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in android/gradle.properties.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in android/gradlew.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in android/keystores/BUCK.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in android/keystores/debug.keystore.properties.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in android/settings.gradle.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in app.json.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in ios/AuraiId-tvOS/Info.plist.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in ios/AuraiId-tvOSTests/Info.plist.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in ios/AuraiId.xcodeproj/xcshareddata/xcschemes/AuraiId-tvOS.xcscheme.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in ios/AuraiId.xcodeproj/xcshareddata/xcschemes/AuraiId.xcscheme.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in ios/AuraiId/AppDelegate.h.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in ios/AuraiId/AppDelegate.m.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in ios/AuraiId/Base.lproj/LaunchScreen.xib.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in ios/AuraiId/Images.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/Contents.json.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in ios/AuraiId/Info.plist.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in ios/AuraiId/main.m.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in ios/AuraiIdTests/AuraiIdTests.m.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in ios/AuraiIdTests/Info.plist.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in android/app/src/main/java/com/auraiid/MainActivity.java.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in android/app/src/main/java/com/auraiid/MainApplication.java.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
git-upgrade info Commit old version template
git-upgrade info Install the new version
error Command failed.
Exit code: 1
Command: git
Arguments: pull
Directory: C:\Users\Ando\AppData\Local\Yarn\cache\v1\.tmp\a3450fedabcb67009ae55c8f322f57b0
Output:
fatal: No remote repository specified.  Please, specify either a URL or a
remote name from which new revisions should be fetched.
git-upgrade ERR! An error occurred during upgrade:
git-upgrade ERR! Error: Command 'yarn add react-native@0.48.4 react@16.0.0-alpha.12' exited with code 1:
stderr: undefinederror Command failed.
Exit code: 1
Command: git
Arguments: pull
Directory: C:\Users\Ando\AppData\Local\Yarn\cache\v1\.tmp\a3450fedabcb67009ae55c8f322f57b0
Output:
fatal: No remote repository specified.  Please, specify either a URL or a
remote name from which new revisions should be fetched.

stdout: yarn add v0.24.5
[1/4] Resolving packages...
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add for documentation about this command.

    at ChildProcess.child.on.code (C:/Users/Ando/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/react-native-git-upgrade/cliEntry.js:58:18)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:215:12)
git-upgrade ERR! Restore initial sources
Note: checking out 'project-snapshot'.

You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make experimental
changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits you make in this
state without impacting any branches by performing another checkout.

If you want to create a new branch to retain commits you create, you may
do so (now or later) by using -b with the checkout command again. Example:

  git checkout -b <new-branch-name>

HEAD is now at adaaa8d... Project snapshot
```

What should I do?

My Current React Native : 0.44.0

git version 2.13.1.windows.2

Yarn version 0.24.5

Comment: Running into this right now :). Did you solve this by any chance? ...I'm wondering whether this may be related to NativeSeed which I used to bootstrap my project.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had a server folder for my backend and I accidently created a git init or initial git repo on that folder and then I was trying to push code on my main folder or root folder and because of that Server folder's git repo my main/root folder was giving me errors like "the file has working directory and LF will be replaced with CRLF", etc. So I just removed the git repo or .git from both root and server folders and then retried it and this time it worked.

Check your folders that if any folder have git repo init or did you run git init code on any folder like me xD. **If you want to remove a git repo completely then use the following command :**

***rm -rf .git***
(-rf will force removing git repo)

Try this and then push or upgrade git...

I hope this is helpful for you. :)